# web deploy c# web application with web api's

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, webdeploy

I made a very simple web application from the web application template. Then I added a web api controller, added global.asax and an entity framework based database. When running in VS2012, everything works fine. The web api returns the expected requested stuff from the database. So far so good. Now I want to deploy this to an productive machine using web deploy 3.5. So I do Publish/Create web deploy package/etc. Then copy the package to a production machine and do .cmd /y and all installs fine. But when I try to browse the site I first I receive and error that tells me that there is a duplicate 'entityframework' section in my web.config (well, there's NOT), but OK, I renamed some stuff to get it to work, but now my web api url does not respond =(

Sigh, are there any recommendations how to use this web deploy thing or how can I just make sure that what I created in VS2012 and works on IISExpress, to port it to another web server?

This is really driving me nuts and I spent a lot of time on this.
Anyone please???
BR,
Ronald

Comment: More information could do here - when you say it doesn't respond, what happens? 404? No response? 500? And what did you have to wrangle in the Web.Config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ronald please take a look here,maybe it might help you.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394698(VS.100).aspx